# What should I do if an ADC is communicating over SPI differently than in the data sheet?

Tags: adc, spi

I am trying to get a voltage reading from a MAX1142BCAP+ with a Raspberry Pi 4B. I am just using the default circuit at the bottom of the datasheet and this code for SPI in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import spidev

# ams or aquisition mode select can either be 0 or 1, 1 being long, 0 being short

spi = spidev.SpiDev()

def adc_spi(ams):
    spi.open(0, 0)
    spi.max_speed_hz = 500000
    spi.mode = 0b00
    spi.writebytes2([0b11100000])
    pressure = spi.readbytes(6)
    print(pressure)
    spi.close()

adc_spi(0)
```

When I run this code I get these outputs in console without changing the voltage on Ain.

```
pi@gauge:~ $ python3 adc1.py
[40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
pi@gauge:~ $ python3 adc1.py
[64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
pi@gauge:~ $ python3 adc1.py
[64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
pi@gauge:~ $ python3 adc1.py
[80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
pi@gauge:~ $ python3 adc1.py
[80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

When I analyze the digital outputs with a logic analyzer I get outputs like these:

[image]

These outputs change each time I run this but the values don't match the voltage I give Ain. These outputs don't match what the datasheet says I should get, either.

Some things I think the problem could be:

- The fact I am not resetting between runs maybe.
- The SPI mode although I have read the datasheet quite a few times by now.

Other then that I have no clue.

I have reconnected everything several times and tested each of my jumpers. I have tried another chip just in case this one was broken. I know this is a noob question this is my first time using SPI any insight you could give for trouble shooting this would be appreciated. Or if you think its probably a lost cause and I should just buy a I2C ADC that would be helpful too.

[This is the datasheet I am using.](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1142-MAX1143.pdf)

Comment: So what **is** the voltage at AIN? Does the ADC output change in a predictable way if you make large changes to the input voltage? What happens if you call adc_spi() several times in the same program, without resetting the SPI interface? What is the purpose of the ams parameter?

Comment: What are the "jumpers" you refer to? Is this assembled on some kind of wireless breadboard? What is the source of the input voltage?

Comment: I have tried a range of voltages from 0 to 12 volts and the output is always 40, 64, or 80. The jumpers I used are just wires to connect the pi. If i call adc_spi multiple times. i get [64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: The AMS parameter selects between internal sampling modes for the ADC; 0 is 24 clocks per conversion and 1 is 32. @ElliotAlderson

Comment: Why does your trace for MOSI not match the `0b11100000` value you're writing?

Comment: How are you connecting the MAX1142 data out (MOSI) to the Raspberry Pi, directly or through a 5V to 3V level translator? And what voltage you are supplying to MAX1142 AVDD and DVDD, 5V or 3V?

Comment: @MarkU I am connecting the adc to 5v power and connecting the pins directly the the pi's spi pins.

Comment: @brhans the code that I used for that run used 0b11100111 I just did not realize that the screenshot was from the wrong code.

Comment: As a test, can you try with AIN = REF (expect full scale code) and another test with AIN = GND (expect near 0).

Comment: The MISO input of the SPI analyzer in your screenshot is not set to the correct channel. I can't quite tell, but it looks like the actual MISO channel is showing the correct data; it might match your python results.
Please post a copy of the capture. Also, you can get the new Saleae Logic 2 alpha software here: https://ideas.saleae.com/f/changelog/